# How can we add custom logic while installing exe created by installshield

Tags: vb6, registry, exe, installshield

Is there any way to add custom logic which should be executed while installing the application created by installshield wizard ? Logic i need to implement includes checking internet connection and searching for key in registry ,if the conditions are valid then continue installing application else show message to user and stop installation . i have searched for options in installshield wizard but i didn't find any solution.
I even made a logic diagram

[image]

By the way i am using vb6 .

Comment: Anything labeled "wizard" suggests a simplified, automatic, generic process.  "Wizard" plus "custom" sounds like an oxymoron.  My guess is that you would need to set the "wizard" aside and learn more about using this product in non-novice mode.

Comment: @Bob77 yes i understand wizard means a simplified ,automatic ,generic process ,but in some cases there exist a functionality where we can use it in our way . likewise in Installshield there is functionality where we can add custom installscript and call dll via installscript . in my case i made a dll to check internet connection and registry value ,so problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

After some research i ended up with the installscript solution . In installshiled we can add InstallScript and sequence it in different event , for checking internet connection and registry value etc ..i made a custom dll to check my logic and called it via installscript . [this](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield17helplib/IHelpIScriptCallingDLLFunction.htm) link will be useful if we have to call dll function via installscript.Here is   code snippet to use dll function in installscript

```
prototype [CallingConvention] [ReturnType] DLLName.FunctionName( ParamType1, ParamType2, ... );
```

For example:

```
prototype BOOL ConnectionCheckdll.CheckInternetConnection( INT, INT, INT );
UseDLL( SUPPORTDIR ^ "ConnectionCheckdll.dll" );
bResult = ConnectionCheckdll.CheckInternetConnection( nInt1, nInt2, nInt3 );
UnUseDLL( SUPPORTDIR ^ "ConnectionCheckdll.dll" );
```